# Q&A Schema doesn't recognize title

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

```json
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "QAPage",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "اقدام برای بارداری بچه پسر",
    "keywords": "اقدام بارداری , تعیین جنسیت",
    "upvoteCount": "196",
    "text": "توضیحات: سلام. خانمی ۳۹ ساله هستم. میخوام تا چهار ماه دیگه اقدام به بارداری کنم. ولی همسرم برای جنسیت بچه تاکید دارند که پسر باشه. و میخواد که مشاوره کنیم که آیا میتونیم کاری کنیم که جنسیت بچه رو چیزی که میخوایم باشه.",
    "dateCreated": "2010-11-04T20:07Z",
    "author": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "سارا"
    },
    "answerCount": "3",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "upvoteCount": "1337",
      "url": "https://www.sample.com/fa/question/4997/اقدام-برای-بارداری-بچه-پسر#ans_3827",
      "text": "توضیحات زیاد در علم سنتی امده که در گوگل موجوداند ولی هیچکدام قطعیت ندارند و قطعی ترین روش لقاح خارج از رحم است که جنس مورد نظر را حفظ و جنسی را که دلخواه نیست حذف می کنیم که البته اخلاقی نی",
      "dateCreated": "2010-12-01T22:01Z",
      "author": {
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "دکتر فروزان سیاوش موخر"
      }
    },
    "suggestedAnswer": [
      {
        "@type": "Answer",
        "upvoteCount": "39",
        "url": "https://www.sample.com/fa/question/4997/اقدام-برای-بارداری-بچه-پسر#ans_3838",
        "text": "با سلام از ۴الی۵ماه قبل از اقدام به باروری ،باید زوجین توسط متخصص تغذیه و رژیم درمانی شروع به رژیم کنند و ۹۸٪نتیجه تعیین جنسیت ،به ثمر میرسد\u200C.",
        "dateCreated": "2010-12-06T21:11Z",
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "دکتر جعفر رضایی"
        }
      },
      {
        "@type": "Answer",
        "upvoteCount": "39",
        "url": "https://www.sample.com/fa/question/4997/اقدام-برای-بارداری-بچه-پسر#ans_3871",
        "text": "توصیه های تغذیه ای پایه علمی ندارد و تنها روش تعیین جنسیت روشهای کمک باروری است.",
        "dateCreated": "2010-12-06T21:11Z",
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "دکتر نعمت اله قربانی"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The result of this code is something like this:

[image]

Google doesn't recognize the title of the question.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's populated by the page title, i.e. the `<title>` element, rather than anything in the structured data. As you're only testing a block of JSON-LD without the surrounding HTML there's no title; hence the "Untitled" snippet preview.

Test the same code with the page HTML and a populated `<title>`, and you should see that `<title>` value in the preview.